# When executing a command in a perl script can perl respond to a STDOUT request posed in the command?

Tags: perl

I'm executing a command inside a perl script and when that command completes, a question is sent to STDOUT requesting a Y or N answer to a question. If no answer is given (i.e. I just end the script) then we have a hung process in the shell waiting for an answer. How can I supply the desired Y answer?

perl v5.8.4
solaris 10

Comment: Note: the command inside the script is posing the question, not the perl script. So what is the method of sending the answer to the shell where the command was executed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- **Simplest**:

  Use shell's ability to redirect "Y" into command's STDIN:

  ```
  `echo "Y" | your_command_expecting_Y`;
  ```

  or (slightly worse but more flexible).

  ```
  `your_command_expecting_Y < /my/file/containing/one/line/with_Y_in_it.txt`;
  ```
- **More complicated but infinitely more flexible and Perl native:**

  Use [`Expect`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Expect.pm) module

  ```
  use Expect;
  # create an Expect object by spawning another process
  my $exp = Expect->spawn($command, @params);
  $exp->send("Y\n");
  ```

Answer (score 3):

[Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Expect)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you *always* want to answer 'Y' and the command will only prompt *once*:

```
system("echo Y | your_command_here");
```

If the command will prompt more than once and you *always* want to answer 'Y':

```
system("yes Y | your_command_here");
```

Otherwise, `Expect` is probably your best bet as the others have suggestes.